# multiple http requests at once using threads

Tags: python, http

Is it possible to preform multiple http requests at once in order to make for a faster request time, I was thinking that I could use threading to do so, thus my question is would this be possible and if so would it be the most efficient way to solve my problem, and then if that is so then how would you do such solution in python?  Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). **Research, try something, add your code & point your problem.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the most iconic example of multithreading usage.

```
import threading
import urllib2
import time

start = time.time()
urls = ["http://www.google.com", "http://www.apple.com", "http://www.microsoft.com", "http://www.amazon.com", "http://www.facebook.com"]

def fetch_url(url):
    urlHandler = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    html = urlHandler.read()
    print "'%s\' fetched in %ss" % (url, (time.time() - start))

threads = [threading.Thread(target=fetch_url, args=(url,)) for url in urls]
for thread in threads:
    thread.start()
for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```

But you should be aware that you can easily be banned by the service for big amount of simultaneous requests

Comment: lets say I had a list of 500 urls that I wanted to make requests to but if I try to put them all in threads then it won't let me, so how would I do this?

Comment: If they are from the different domains that there won't be any problems, but if you try to crawl different URL's from one site then there is a big probability that it will ban you.

Comment: lets say that I had a url that I wanted to make like 500 requests to(assuming that they wouldn't ban me) but when I try to it gives me a thread error because with the code above it is trying to make 500 different threads, then what would I do?

Comment: in such a situation you can use ThreadPool with max_size and add threads there. It will run no more then max_size amount of threads simultaneously, and after one thread finishes, it will add run the next one.